# C++, Embedded Linux, For Video HDMI Input/Output

Tags: c++, c, linux, video, embedded

This is a newbie question, but here we go...

I would like to know how I would go about programming a small embedded linux board (I was thinking a TI Divinci based board)  for a video input (via HDMI or Component) and then output to a TV (via the same HDMI connection).

Along with the original video pass through, I would like to have an HTML frame at the bottom of the television screen.

Any help or a good reference for a starting point would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On the TI DaVinci this is super simple.

The video driver and the video-backend support multiple overlays.

You'll stream your video to the lowest video surface, draw onto an overlay-surface (3 bit of alpha-blending is supported in hardware) and presto: The video output will contain the video-source and your overlay.

I don't know if grabbing a video signal from HDMI is supported though. Composite for sure is..

---

Btw: If you're looking for a graphic API with performance take a look at this product:

http://www.tesbv.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=42&Itemid=94

I've written the core graphic routines for it and I know that it blows DirectFB out of the water..

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I was wondering, where would be a good place to start learning about the C++ coding involved to code the streaming portion of this?  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

The de facto non-X graphics library for Linux is [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/). I'm not sure how well it supports HDMI though.

Comment: I couldn't find with keyword HDMI at the link. Would you add more details, thank.